# Creating test application by restoring database in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

We have planned to migrate our SharePoint server 2010 to SharePoint Online (Office 365). Before we migrate our production site, we have tried to create a test environment in SharePoint server 2010 using the backup data of our production sites. We have tried the below steps to create a Staging environment as like our Production environment. Can anyone suggest the steps for migration or the steps we have followed is good.

Steps :

1. I have backup the content database.
2. Created a new web application and restored the backup database to this web   application.
3. As the site is    not loading and hence we created a new site
   collection.
4. Once the new    site collection is created, the site is able to load but the site and    content of production site is not restored as like in our testing  site.

Will restoring the database is enough to restore the site collection in the application in SharePoint or need to restore the site separately to the web application. Any suggested solution will be grateful for me to proceed.

Thank you and Best Regards,
Ragunaathan M P

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a test environment to use for SharePoint online your best bet is to use the 2016 bits.  When you move your content over you need to do make sure you have upgraded the content.

So you would do some flavor of the following:

1) Backup the existing database

2) Restore the DB to the new farm

3) Mount the DB (Mount-SPContentDatabase xxx)

At this point (this is very overly simplified you should be able to render the sites.

Lots of other factors will be involved (InfoPath, Full Trust Code, Workflows, etc).  However if your content is pretty vanilla this is what I would do.  Dp not use the nob2bsiteupgrade option on mount or you will have an upgraded database schema, but your sites won't work.

To validate your upgrade check the logs and look at the versions table in the database.  You should see a 16.x.x.x version.  The other numbers are the upgrader actions and won't tell you much.

Here are some references:

[Upgrade Content](https://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/cc263299%28v=office.16%29.aspx)

[Upgrade-SPContentDatabase](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607813.aspx)

[Mount-SPContentDatabase](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607581.aspx)

Comment: Sorry I misread you are going from 2010.  You need to go to SP 2013 first I believe to get to SP2016. I don't believe you can skip the middle step.